# How to detect the last line in awk before END?

Tags: awk, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate String values and print them, but if the last types are Strings and there is no change of type then the concatenation won't print:

input.txt:

```
String 1
String 2
Number 5
Number 2
String 3
String 3
```

awk:

```
awk '

BEGIN { tot=0; ant_t=""; }

{ 
  t = $1; val=$2;
  #if string, concatenate its value
  if (t == "String") {
    tot+=val;
    nx=1;
  } else {
    nx=0; 
  }
  #if type change, add tot to res
  if (t != "String" && ant_t == "String") {
    res=res tot;
    tot=0;
  }
  ant_t=t;
  #if string, go next
  if (nx == 1) {
    next;
  }
  res=res"\n"val;
}

END { print res; }' input.txt
```

Current output:

```
3
5
2
```

Expected output:

```
3
5
2
6
```

How can I detect if awk is reading last line, so if there won't be change of type it will check if it is the last line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` reads line by line hence it cannot determine if it is reading the last line or not. The `END` block can be useful to perform actions once the end of file has reached.

To perform what you expect

```
awk '/String/{sum+=$2} /Number/{if(sum) print sum; sum=0; print $2} END{if(sum) print sum}'
```

will produce output as

```
3
5
2
6
```

what it does?

`/String/` selects line that matches `String` so is `Number`

`sum+=$2` performs the concatanation with `String` lines. When `Number` occurs, print the `sum` and reset to zero

Answer (score 2):

Like this maybe:

```
awk -v lines="$(wc -l < /etc/hosts)" 'NR==lines{print "LAST"};1' /etc/hosts
```

I am pre-calculating the number of lines (using `wc`) and passing that into `awk` as a variable called `lines`, if that is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '$1~"String"{x+=$2;y=1}$1~"Number"{if (y){print x;x=0;y=0;}print $2}END{if(y) print x}' file
```

**Explanation**

- `y` is used as a `boolean`, and I check at the `END` if the last pattern was a `string` and print the sum
- You can actually use `x` as the boolean like [nu11p01n73R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26378154/3909469) does which is smarter

**Test**

```
$ cat file
String 1
String 2
Number 5
Number 2
String 3
String 3
$ awk '$1~"String"{x+=$2;y=1}$1~"Number"{if (y){print x;x=0;y=0;}print $2}END{if(y) print x}' file
3
5
2
6
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change last line to:

```
END { print res; print tot;}'
```

Comment: It will print 0 if last type will be != String.